# Password Check for Special Characters

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My password setup requires that the user uses a **special** character. I've written some **JavaScript**, which works fairly well, but having issues checking for the `\ ] -` characters. How can I implement these characters into the code below?

**Clarification:** I am only using JavaScript for the initial check. There is C#, which also handles validation!

**Current JavaScript, which is working**

```
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~,+,=,`,(,),|,\,.,/,{,},:,;,",',[,-,])/)) {
                $('#successImage').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#passwordImage').addClass('shown');
                count++;
            }
```

Comment: I hope you are not relying *only* on javascript to make that check and that is why you have C# tag there.

Comment: @Habib, I am not only relying on JavaScript, that would be a bad idea! lol This is just the initial check.

Comment: Please define "special". (What about punctuation other than the characters you've shown?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\\` instead of `\`.

```
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~,+,=,`,(,),|,\\,.,/,{,},:,;,",',[,-,\]])) {
            $('#successImage').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#passwordImage').addClass('shown');
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: this did the trick; thanks so much. I'll mark this as the answer in 6 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var regExp = /.*[!,%,&,@@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~,+,=,`,(,),|,\,.,/,{,},:,;,",',[\]]/;
   if(!regExp.test($("#password").val())){
     console.log("insert new password");
   } else {
     console.log("well done my friend");
   }
```